# Replacing a special identifier pattern with re.sub in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex and have a regex replacement in a `re.sub` that I can't figure out.

```
import re

test_cases = [
    "1-Some String #0123",
    "2-Some String #1234-56-a",
    "3-Some String #1234-56A ",
    "4-Some String (Fubar/ #12-345-67A)",
    "5-Some String (Fubar - #12-345.67 A)",
    "6-Some String / #123",
    "7-Some String/#0233",
    "8-Some #1 String/#0233"
    ]

for test in test_cases:
    test = re.sub(r'[/|#][A-Z|a-z|0-9|-]*','', test)
    print(test)
```

The code should print:

```
1-Some String
2-Some String
3-Some String
4-Some String (Fubar)
5-Some String (Fubar)
6-Some String
7-Some String   
8-Some #1 String
```

But, instead I am currently getting this (with 4,5,8 not fully converted):

```
1-Some String 
2-Some String 
3-Some String  
4-Some String (Fubar )
5-Some String (Fubar - .67 A)
6-Some String  
7-Some String
8-Some  String
```

Comment: You haven't included spaces or dots in your regex so they won't match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
import re

test_cases = [
    "1-Some String #0123",
    "2-Some String #1234-56-a",
    "3-Some String #1234-56A ",
    "4-Some String (Fubar/ #12-345-67A)",
    "5-Some String (Fubar - #12-345.67 A)",
    "6-Some String / #123",
    "7-Some String/#0233",
    "8-Some #1 String/#0233"
    ]

for test in test_cases:
    test = re.sub(r'\s*([/#]|- )[\sA-Za-z0-9-#\.]*(?=(\)|$))','', test)
    print(test)
```

Result:

```
1-Some String
2-Some String
3-Some String
4-Some String (Fubar)
5-Some String (Fubar)
6-Some String
7-Some String
8-Some #1 String
```

The regex (substring to delete) can be defined as:

- To start with "/", "#" or "- "
- May be preceded by whitespace(s)
- To consist of whitespaces, alphanumerics, hyphens, hashes or dots
- To be anchored by "end of line" or ")" by using a positive lookahead

Then the regex will look like:
`\s*([/#]|- )[\sA-Za-z0-9-#\.]*(?=(\)|$))`

`positive lookahead` may require some explanation. The pattern `(?=regex)`
is a zero-width assertion meaning `followed by regex`.
The benefit is the matched substring does not include the `regex` and
you can use it as an `anchor`.

Comment: could kindly provide some explanation of your pattern.  Tx.

Comment: @SanV I've updated my answer with some explanations. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution....  I compared this to the one provided by 'The fourth bird'.  So basically comparing  '\s*([/#]|- )[\sA-Za-z0-9-#\.]*(?=(\)|$))'    to   '\s*([/#]|- )[\sA-Za-z0-9-#\.]*(?=(\)|$))' as I was curious about the performance.  It appeared that latter one is a bit faster (about 10%).  Not sure why though.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to match only the last occurrence of # using a negative lookahead `(?![^#\n\r]*#)`. For clarity  I have put matching a space `[ ]` between square brackets.

```
[ ]*(?:[/-][ ]*)?#(?![^#\n\r]*#)[\da-zA-Z. -]+
```

**Explanation**

- `[ ]*` Match 0+ times a space
- `(?:[/-][ ]*)?` Optionally match `/` or `-` and 0+ spaces
- `#` Match literally
- `(?![^#\n\r]*#)` Negative lookahead, assert when is om the right does not contain `#`
- `[\da-zA-Z. -]+` Match 1+ times what is listed in the character class

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PTbNVJ/2)

In the replacement use an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to do it in two steps:

First: Clean up the part in parenthesis.  After the '(' and some letters remove everything up to the closing ')'.

Second: Remove the unwanted stuff at the end of a line.  A line ends either at '#' followed by 2 or more digits or a '/'.  There may be a space before the '#' or '/'.

```
import re

paren_re = re.compile(r"([(][a-zA-Z]+)([^)]*)")

eol_re = re.compile(r"(.*?)\s*(?:#\d\d|/).*")

for line in test_cases:
    result = paren_re.sub(r"\1", line)
    result = eol_re.sub(r"\1", result)

    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fit them into one regex, maybe someone can. Here's a 2-line solution:

```py
import re

test_cases = [
    "1-Some String #0123",
    "2-Some String #1234-56-a",
    "3-Some String #1234-56A ",
    "4-Some String (Fubar/ #12-345-67A)",
    "5-Some String (Fubar - #12-345.67 A)",
    "6-Some String / #123",
    "7-Some String/#0233",
    "8-Some #1 String/#0233"
    ]

for test in test_cases:
    test = re.sub(r'[\/#][\w\s\d\-]*', '', test)
    test = re.sub(r'[\s\.\-\d]+\w+\)', ')', test)
    print(test)
```

Output:

```
1-Some String
2-Some String
3-Some String
4-Some String (Fubar)
5-Some String (Fubar)
6-Some String
7-Some String
8-Some
```

Explain:

1. `\w` for `a-zA-Z`
2. `\d` for `0-9`
3. `\s` for spaces
4. `\.` for dot
5. `\-` for minus

---

But I'm confused with your last line of output, why it outputs `#1 String`, based on what? If you confirm that you can write a specific regex for that pattern.

Comment: You're missing parts in Line 8 :p :)  Looks like @tshiono 's 1-line pattern works